# How to delete the saved facebook application from codeigniter?

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

Can any body help me how to delete the facebook saved app using php codeigniter.

Here is my code first i load the fb library then how to delete the the specific app using this library?

```
$this->load->library('facebook');
$user = $this->facebook->user();
//here how to send a request to the facebook to delete an requested application
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't delete a Facebook app via an api call. See the docs http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/

Comment: why would you want to delete a facebook app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot delete a Facebook application from your code. The CodeIgniter library you're loading here is for accessing the public Facebook API and getting details about users, etc.

If you want to delete a Facebook application you created then you can do that in the application control panel on Facebook.

If you want to delete a Facebook application someone else created then you would have to petition Facebook to do that via email but I doubt that's what you want to do nor would you be able to achieve it.

If you want to delete the application for the user (i.e. revoke the application access via the API) then you have to tell the user to do that themselves. The Facebook API does not allow you to manipulate another users Facebook account.

If it's your own account then log in and remove the application via your user profile.

Basically what you're asking isn't possible in the Facebook API and doesn't have anything to do with CodeIgniter.